# ajax.actionlink is resending the entire page content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i have been trying to implemet ajax.actionlink in asp.net mvc 3.below is my code for ajax.action link

```
<div id="changing-content">

 </div>

 @Ajax.ActionLink("Next","Phone",new {id = 2},new AjaxOptions { 
HttpMethod="Get",
UpdateTargetId = "changing-content",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

 });
```

and the controller

```
public ActionResult Phones(int ? id) {
    if (id == null) id = 1;
    Models.Phones phonoes = new Models.Phones();
    //  return View(new Models.PhonesList { phonesList = paginateRsult(id,        "").ToList() });
    return View(paginateRsult(id, "").ToList());
}
```

when i click on link it just resend the entire page content and adds in the div which i passed to ajax option.

Comment: Not sure this is the issue but your @Ajax.ActionLink has the ActionName as "Phone". I think that need to be 'Phones'. I thought you should also return a PartialView instead.

Comment: Raj@ yeah i tried and found the answer an hour ago..just the way you said..return a partial view